# Simple php/mysql log-in form security

Tags: php, html, mysql, security

Id like to make a simple login form for a website

```
    <form action="ContactFormHandler.php" method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Username:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Password:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="password" name="password" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Your Email:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="Email" name="Email" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center;">
                    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
                    <input type="reset" id="reset" value="Reset" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
```

You see where it says contact form handler? I would like the form, and the file handling the form to be the same file.  2 in 1.

how do I include this contact handler in the same file of the contact form?

```
<?php
$contactName = $_POST["ContactName"];
$contactEmail = $_POST["ContactEmail"];
$contactPassword = $_POST["ContactLeastFavoriteColor"];
$sql_connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root");
mysql_select_db("MyRadContactForm", $sql_connection);
$sql = "INSERT INTO MyRadContacts (
            ContactName,
            ContactEmail,
            ContactPassword,
            ContactDateCreated
        )
        VALUES (
            '$contactName',
            '$contactEmail',
            '$contactPassword',
            NOW()
        )";

mysql_query($sql, $sql_connection);
mysql_close($sql_connection);
?>
```

Comment: You are open to SQLInjection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Make the form submit to its own page**

Change the form's `action` to `action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>"` to make the form submit to the same page

**Process the form within the page**

Put a check around your PHP code to see whether or not the form was submitted:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    [your processing code here]
} else {
    [display form]
}
```

(be sure to add `name="submit"` to your submit button)

Comment: but he is asking about how to use 1 file instead of 2 files, he is not asking anything else

Comment: @ispu it is irrelevant. teaching wrong techniques have to be avoided.

Comment: @WebnetMobile.com that is sure but no one is answering his question first of all :)

Comment: -1 This code is vulnerable to xss and the OP's code is vulnerable to SQLi.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use `.php` extension to your file to include all your code in 1 file cause:

`login.php` can contain both `html` and `php`

`login.html` can contain `html` but not `php` code

so you can do all in once by creating a `login.php` file :

```
<?php
$contactName = $_POST["ContactName"];
$contactEmail = $_POST["ContactEmail"];
$contactPassword = $_POST["ContactLeastFavoriteColor"];
$sql_connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root");
mysql_select_db("MyRadContactForm", $sql_connection);
$sql = "INSERT INTO MyRadContacts (
            ContactName,
            ContactEmail,
            ContactPassword,
            ContactDateCreated
        )
        VALUES (
            '$contactName',
            '$contactEmail',
            '$contactPassword',
            NOW()
        )";

mysql_query($sql, $sql_connection);
mysql_close($sql_connection);
?>


<!--your html code here -->
```

also please check your code to be safe on `SQLinjection`, google for that if you  want to have some tips to follow, and sorry for my bad english

Comment: All of you guys really helped me. I want to 1 up everyone. Someone down-voted me so I lost the 15 points. I can't vote up.

Answer (score 1):

Name your submit button so you can check if it was present in the request or not. If not, show the form, if it is in request, then you were invoked from the form - store your data in DB.

More/less your code should look like this:

```
<?php

if( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) {

   $contactName = $_POST["ContactName"];
   $contactEmail = $_POST["ContactEmail"];
   $contactPassword = $_POST["ContactLeastFavoriteColor"];
   $sql_connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root");
   mysql_select_db("MyRadContactForm", $sql_connection);
   $sql = "INSERT INTO MyRadContacts (
               ContactName,
               ContactEmail,
               ContactPassword,
               ContactDateCreated
           )
           VALUES (
               '$contactName',
               '$contactEmail',
               '$contactPassword',
               NOW()
           )";

   mysql_query($sql, $sql_connection);
   mysql_close($sql_connection);

} else {

?>

   <form action="ContactFormHandler.php" method="post">
     <table>
         <tr>
             <td>Username:</td>
             <td><input type="text" id="username" name="username" /></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>Password:</td>
             <td><input type="text" id="password" name="password" /></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>Your Email:</td>
             <td><input type="text" id="Email" name="Email" /></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center;">
                 <input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
                 <input type="reset" id="reset" value="Reset" />
             </td>
         </tr>
     </table>
   </form>

<?php

} // end of else

?>
```

You are still open to SQL Injection and your code does not seem to handle any errors (neither lack of data from form like empty fields nor code failures) but that's outside the scope of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Use this approach

Check for form submit

```
<?php
if($_POST['login_submit'] ==1){
    //process your logic here
}
?>
```

Modify your form

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="login_submit" value="1">
....
.....
</form>
```